# Create MDTextFieldRound with python

Tags: python, widget, kivy

This code compile correctly.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRect

from kivy.lang import Builder

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        l = BoxLayout()
        self.screen.add_widget(l)
        w = MDTextFieldRect()
        l.add_widget(w)

App().run()
```

But If you just change the widget from `MDTextFieldRect` to `MDTextFieldRound` or `MDTextField`, the application will crash and I don't know why (there is no apparent error message).

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRound

from kivy.lang import Builder

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Screen()
        return self.screen

    def on_start(self):
        l = BoxLayout()
        self.screen.add_widget(l)
        w = MDTextFieldRound()
        l.add_widget(w)

App().run()
```

And to confuse me even more, it can work if you use the kv langage !!!

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
Screen:
    
    MDTextFieldRound:
        icon_left: 'key-variant'
        normal_color: app.theme_cls.accent_color
'''

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.screen

App().run()
```

Comment: That is a bug in the KivyMD code. You can report it at [GitHub](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues).

Comment: First time I report an issue on Github, I feel like an advanced programmer now ! xD
[https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/674](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/674)